# No matching constructor found on type

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, exception

I'm making Windows Phone 7.1 app with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

I added this namespace to MainPage.xaml:

```
xmlns:myNameSpace="clr-namespace:MyApp"
```

And this:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <myNameSpace:MyClass x:Key="referenceToMyClass" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

And used like this in same file:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox"
         Height="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=Height}"
         Width="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=Width}"
         ItemsSource="{StaticResource referenceToMyClass}"
         DisplayMemberPath="MyAttribute" />
```

MyClass looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class MyClass : ObservableCollection<AnotherClass>
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Class temp = new AnotherClass("Example attribute");
            Add(temp);
        }

        public void AddAnotherClass(AnotherClass anotherClass)
        {
            Add(anotherClass);
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to Debug it on my cellphone I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
>   Additional information: No matching constructor found on type 'MyApp.MyClass'.

Answer (score 17):

It is because your class is not public.  Should be

```
public class MyClass : ObservableCollection<AnotherClass>
```

XAML cannot bind to non-public objects/classes/properties

Answer (score 2):

You may also get this exception when your code raises a `MissingMethodException` in the constructor of a xaml object:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var t = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), typeof(int)); // Missing constructor
        // or:
        //this.GetType().InvokeMember("NonExistingMember", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this, new object[0]);
    }
}

public class T
{}
```

The xaml parser incorrectly reports that the constructor of the `MainWindow` class was not found. Looking into the "Inner Exception" of the thrown exception reveals the real reason of the failure.

Comment: So what is the resolution for this?

Comment: @Chris For what? That incorrect `MissingMethodException`? Just do not call a non-existing member.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer in the hope that it will provide some help for those that encounter the same particular issue that I did:

TeamCity was failing to build several dependent SilverLight projects reporting a resgen.exe error and the ubiquitous generic error codes that provided no insight at all.

I upgraded the SilverLight projects from v3 to v5 which allowed TeamCity to build, however one of the SilverLight screens was failing to display anything, no errors reported using FireFox.

Through debugging using Visual Studio 2010 and IE I got the same error message as the OP with a variation that it occured at the call to InitializeComponent(), but the difference being that the class was already public?!

The issue was that the upgraded projects were having issues with resource.resx files, upon removing them totally from the SilverLight projects the whole thing worked as intended.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a WPF solution, but I can change anything in the XAML file that contains bindings to the resx file (like, just adding a space somewhere, or removing the same space the next time), and it works. Flaky framework issues.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I'm getting an error from `InitializeComponent()` with the error message that the resource.resx missing contractor. But what is the solution??? Dropping completely the resource.resx isn't a valid solution. So what do you propose?